# How can I prevent Windows 10 from sharing wifi details with my contacts?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, encryption, windows-10, wifisense

In recent release of Windows 10 we could see a new feature named wifi sense, which raised the following security threat as per this [blog post](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/07/windows-10-shares-your-wi-fi-with-contacts/#more-31727) :

> This brilliant new feature, which Microsoft has dubbed Wi-Fi Sense,
>   doesn’t share your WiFi network password per se — it shares an
>   encrypted version of that password. But it does allow anyone in your
>   Skype or Outlook or Hotmail contacts lists to waltz onto your Wi-Fi
>   network — should they ever wander within range of it or visit your
>   home (or hop onto it secretly from hundreds of yards away with a good
>   ‘ole antenna!).

As per faq :

> For networks you choose to share access to, the password is sent over
>   an encrypted connection and stored in an encrypted file on a Microsoft
>   server, and then sent over a secure connection to your contacts’ phone
>   if they use Wi-Fi Sense and they’re in range of the Wi-Fi network you
>   shared

From [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2015/07/wi-fi-sense-in-windows-10-yes-it-shares-your-passkeys-no-you-shouldnt-be-scared/) :

> First, a bit of anti-scaremongering. Despite what you may have read
>   elsewhere, you should not be mortally afraid of Wi-Fi Sense. By
>   default, it will not share Wi-Fi passwords with anyone else. For every
>   network you join, you’ll be asked if you want to share it with your
>   friends/social network

From the above excerpts it's unclear whether Windows 10 shares wifi details with  my contacts; So my questions were few :

Does it really shares WiFi details with my contacts since many articles states it's shared & it's not shared.

If it's shared how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If it's shared how can I prevent it?

You need to give your wireless network a new name with "**_optout**" somewhere in the Wi‑Fi network name (also called the SSID).

Note:

- If you also want to opt out of Google's WiFi network mapping you will also need to include "**_nomap**" as well in your SSID.

---

#### Recommendation

> 1. Prior to upgrade to Windows 10, change your Wi-Fi network name/SSID to something that includes the terms "_nomap_optout".
> 2. After the upgrade is complete, change the privacy settings in Windows to disable Wi-Fi Sense sharing.
> 3. If you haven’t already done so, consider additional steps to harden the security of your Wi-Fi network.

Source [Windows 10 Shares Your Wi-Fi With Contacts](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/07/windows-10-shares-your-wi-fi-with-contacts/)

---

> If you run a Wi-Fi network and you want to prevent Windows 10 (or Windows Phone) users from sharing the passkey via Wi-Fi Sense, you can add _optout to the end of the network SSID. Microsoft notes that, even if you opt out in this way, "It can take several days for your network to be added to the opted-out list for Wi-Fi Sense."

Source [Wi-Fi Sense in Windows 10: Yes, it shares your passkeys; no, you shouldn’t be scared](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/07/wi-fi-sense-in-windows-10-yes-it-shares-your-passkeys-no-you-shouldnt-be-scared/)

---

#### I'm sharing a network and want to stop it. How do I do that?

> If you're sharing Wi‑Fi network access and want to stop sharing a
>   certain network, do the following:
>
> To stop sharing access to a Wi‑Fi network
>
> - Go to Start Start icon > Settings > Network & Internet > Wi‑Fi > Manage Wi‑Fi settings.
> - Under Manage known networks, select the network that you want to stop sharing access to, and then select Stop sharing.
> - It can take a few days for the network to stop being shared. This is also true if a user is already connected to the network.
>
> If you want to stop sharing all Wi‑Fi networks that you're currently
>   sharing, go to Start Start icon > Settings > Network & Internet >
>   Wi‑Fi > Manage Wi‑Fi settings, and then turn off Connect to networks
>   shared by my contacts under Wi‑Fi Sense. It can take a few days for
>   the networks to which you've shared access to stop being shared. When
>   you turn this setting off, you won't get connected to Wi‑Fi networks
>   that your contacts have shared with you.

Source [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq)

---

#### How do I opt my Wi‑Fi network out of Wi‑Fi Sense?

> If you don't want Wi‑Fi Sense to connect people to your open Wi‑Fi network or allow people to share access to your password-protected network, you can opt your network out of it by including _optout somewhere in the Wi‑Fi network name (also called the SSID). For example, mynetwork_optout or my_optout_network. When it comes to sharing, you might choose to do this if you have a Wi‑Fi network at home or at a small business where other people know the Wi‑Fi network password, but you don’t want to allow your network to be shared.

Source [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq)

---

#### How to disable Wi-Fi Sense in Windows 10

> First, open the Start menu and head to Settings > Network & Internet >
>   Wi-Fi > Manage Wi-Fi settings. In here, you basically want to disable
>   every option you see, as well as tell Windows 10 to forget any Wi-Fi
>   networks you’ve signed into in the past.
>
> [image]
>
> That’s easy, and all well and good. But what if you don’t want your
>   friends sharing the information about your network’s password with
>   their friends? That takes some additional tinkering, and it’s not
>   obvious. There isn’t a mere option toggle in Windows 10 itself.
>
> Instead, you need to dive into your actual router’s settings and give
>   your network a new name with “_optout” at the end. For example, a
>   network called “WiFiSenseUgh_optout” wouldn’t be stored by Wi-Fi
>   Sense, while one that’s just called “WiFiSenseUgh” would be usable
>   with Microsoft’s sharing feature.
>
> Yeah, it’s a pain, but if you don’t add “_optout” to your network and
>   want to stay out of Microsoft’s Wi-Fi Sense database, you’ll need to
>   manually enter your password on your friends’ devices when they pop by
>   your house and make sure to uncheck Windows 10’s “Share network with
>   my contacts” box when you do so.

Source [How to disable Windows 10's Wi-Fi Sense password sharing](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2951824/windows/how-to-disable-windows-10s-wi-fi-sense-password-sharing.html)

---

#### The Microsoft server might already have a copy of my wifi credentials.

You can change your Wifi credentials. It is a good idea to regularly change them in any case.

> It can take several days for your network to be added to the opted-out list for Wi‑Fi Sense. If you want to stop your network from being shared sooner than that, you can change your Wi‑Fi network password. For more info about how to do that, check the documentation for your router or access point.

Source [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq)

---

#### How do I opt out from Google's Location Mapping?

> How do I prevent my wireless access point from being collected?
>
> Mozilla's client applications do not collect information about WiFi
>   access points whose SSID is hidden or ends with the string "_nomap".
>   If you would like to prevent your WiFi access point from being
>   reported to this service, you can rename your SSID to append "_nomap"
>   to the name (e.g., SSID "MyWirelessNetwork" becomes
>   "MyWirelessNetwork_nomap") or configure your SSID to be hidden.
>
> This approach is used by other companies offering similar services. We
>   have chosen to follow the example established by others, to make sure
>   you do not have to learn about specific ways to opt-out of this
>   service, but can generally signal your desire to do so and have that
>   signal be respected by multiple services.

Source [How do I prevent my wireless access point from being collected?](https://location.services.mozilla.com/optout)

---

#### Further reading

- [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq)

Comment: but what it scares is ,the microsoft server might already have a copy of my  wifi credentials ,if we give optout we were not sure whether it would be removed permanently,can we take it as temporary solution?

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 - So change those credentials.  What they have stored is an encrypted hash of the password.  They don't actually store or share the **actual** password.

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 
You can change your Wifi credentials. It is a good idea to regularly change them in any case.

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 Answer updated

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Do you have a source for this? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq says "For networks you choose to share access to, the password is sent over an encrypted connection and is stored in an encrypted file on a Microsoft server, and is then sent over an HTTPS connection to your contacts' PC or phone if they use Wi‑Fi Sense. Your contacts don't get to see your password, and you don't get to see theirs."

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the quotes you provided:

> For networks **you choose to share access to**,

and

> **By default, it will not share Wi-Fi passwords** with anyone else. For every network you join, **you’ll be asked if you want to share it** with your friends/social network

and there's also been an update added to the first article you quoted:

> ...that **while Wi-Fi Sense is turned on by default, users still have to explicitly choose to share a network**.

So don't share them, and there's no problem. :)

From [MS's FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq) about WiFi Sense on Windows 10 (under "I'm sharing a network and want to stop it. How do I do that?"):

> If you're sharing Wi‑Fi network access and want to stop sharing a certain network, do the following:
>
> To stop sharing access to a Wi‑Fi network
>
> 1. Go to Start Start icon > Settings > Network & Internet > Wi‑Fi > Manage Wi‑Fi settings.
> 2. Under Manage known networks, select the network that you want to stop sharing access to, and then select Stop sharing.
>
> It can take a few days for the network to stop being shared. This is
>   also true if a user is already connected to the network.

Also Microsoft also provides this additional way to prevent sharing:

> You can opt your network out of it by including `_optout` somewhere in the Wi‑Fi network name (also called the SSID). For example, `mynetwork_optout` or `my_optout_network`.

Comment: but what it scares is ,the microsoft server might already have a copy of my  wifi credentials ,if we give optout we were not sure whether it would be removed permanently,can we take it as temporary solution?

Comment: If you're worried, change your current SSID and don't share it with anyone.  If you're worried about *Microsoft* stealing your WiFi password, then your only choice is to stop using Microsoft products and switch to an OS vendor you trust.

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 - They do have a copy. It is encrypted.  They don't even store the password, they store a hash of the password, and that is what is shared.  Your actually password is actually stored on your system, and you system does the work, to figure out if the hash is your password or not.  Android  does something very similar, of course on Android, there is no way to disable it.  At the end of the day you only share the password if you want to.

Comment: @Ramhound: The stored password uses reversible encryption, not a hash, and Microsoft knows how to decrypt it.  A hash wouldn't allow "friends" to join the network, therefore it must be reversible encryption.

Comment: i sort of disagree.  The hash could be sent to your PC, which has to authorize sharing the connections and knows the password, I can easily see how the flow would work