# How to disable and remove Wifi Sense? (Sending your Wifi passwords to Microsoft)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifisense

Can one disable and remove Wifi Sense **completely**?  Perhaps by disabling a service, removing system files, or by registry editing?

I found options and registry keys to stop Microsoft from sharing your Wifi passwords with other people, but I want to disable Wifi Sense completely, so that **not even Microsoft gets my Wifi data.**

How can I do that?

Is Wifi Sense running as a dedicated process or service on my system? Are there more secret registry entries?

This other question ([How can I prevent Windows 10 from sharing wifi details with my contacts?](https://superuser.com/questions/948289/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-sharing-wifi-details-with-my-contacts)) is related, but I want to go a step farther and actually remove the Wifi Sense functionality from my system so that it never has the chance to share any networks.

And yes, I know that you can add _optout to you wifi SSID to disallow sharing of your own wifi's password. But first of all I cannot change my SSID and secondly I'm not only using my own Wifi and I certainly don't want to share other peoples password with Microsoft, can be highly illegal in some circumstances (at work for example).

**EDIT**:
From what I understand, `wcmsvc` is the service responsible for Wifi Sense, but it's also responsible for the Wifi core components itself. So disabling would probably kill Wifi altogether. :/
Another thing I found out is that Wifi Sense seems to store it's registry entries in this key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\wcmsvc\wifinetworkmanager\`
Any idea what all the keys in it do? For example:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\wcmsvc\wifinetworkmanager\crowdsrcplugin\EnableWiFiCrowdsourcing`

Screenshot showing there is no complete disable option:
[image: Wi-Fi Sense screenshot]

Comment: @Ramhound You should also "change your Wi-Fi network name/SSID to something that includes the terms "_nomap_optout". See my answer [How can i prevent my windows 10 from sharing wifi details with my contacts](http://superuser.com/a/948298) for all the details.

Comment: But you can't connect to my Wifi without the password. So are you saying MS is giving them a hack? I can't really think of other ways this could work.

Comment: This question may be difficult to answer, since this is a core part of the OS, there may not be any way to disable it without breaking something else. The best answer I can give right now is to simply not use Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable Wi-Fi Sense by Using registry

1.Press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> ,type `regedit` and open registry editor

2.Navigate to following path

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WcmSvc\wifinetworkmanager\config\
```

3.Right-click in the right pane and select `DWORD (32-bit)`.

Name it `AutoConnectAllowedOEM` and give it a value of **0**.

[image]

It will disable the Wi-fi sense ,

Comment: May I ask how you found out if/that it really disables Wifi Sense?

Comment: I really need to know...  there is only like 14 hours left to award the bounty.

Comment: @Forivin: `AutoConnectAllowedOEM` seems like a possibility and is [documented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3085719) by MS. The problem is that you have no way to test any solution, especially since Windows 10 keeps on evolving.

Comment: <sigh> This registry key doesn't do anything more then what you can do through the interface.  This basically just makes it so it cannot be enabled, and since it disabled by default, this doesn't do very much.  Using `_optout` is by far the better approach since that literally not allow that access point to function.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `_optout`, there are two ways to prevent WiFi Sense from working,
which might not be possible in your case, where I understand you do not control
the environment :

1. One must sign in with Microsoft Account to use WiFi Sense,
   so using a local account in effect disables it totally, as well as
   most other information sharing with Microsoft.
2. WiFi Sense will not share log-in information for networks with [802.1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) authentication, but the infrastructure for using 802.1X is not easy to construct.

Answer (score 3):

Working in IT I looked into this same issue, but the 2 things that people have found and what Microsoft has said is the setting you found in the Wifi Settings and the Wifi SSID.

Maybe in the future someone will find a registry key, but in the Wifi settings you turn off everything in the Wifi Sense menu.  The second thing is to change your Wifi SSID to have _optout or the Wifi SSID and password can still be send to Microsoft's servers.

A note to help, at the very least Microsoft has said once it's on their servers, the information is encrypted before sending to any device, and those devices will not have full access to the network using that feature.  The problem I can see is that people can probably find a way to gain full access to a network, and just because a password is encrypted doesn't mean it's safe.

The only other option is to not use Wifi, but that's too much trouble and in some cases impossible.

Edit: here's some information from Microsoft just to point out the same information you have.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq

> **I'm sharing a network and want to stop it. How do I do that?
>   If you're sharing Wi‑Fi network access and want to stop sharing a certain network, do the following:**
>
> To stop sharing access to a Wi‑Fi network
>
> Go to Start Start icon > Settings > Network & Internet > Wi‑Fi > Manage Wi‑Fi settings.
>   Under Manage known networks, select the network that you want to stop sharing access to, and then select Stop sharing.
>
> It can take a few days for the network to stop being shared. This is also true if a user is already connected to the network.
>
> If you want to stop sharing all Wi‑Fi networks that you're currently sharing, go to Start Start icon > Settings > Network & Internet > Wi‑Fi > Manage Wi‑Fi settings, and then turn off Connect to networks shared by my contacts under Wi‑Fi Sense. It can take a few days for the networks to which you've shared access to stop being shared. When you turn this setting off, you won't get connected to Wi‑Fi networks that your contacts have shared with you.

Here's for the Wifi _optout i mentioned:

> **How do I opt my Wi‑Fi network out of Wi‑Fi Sense?**
>
> If you don't want Wi‑Fi Sense to connect people to your open Wi‑Fi network or allow people to share access to your password-protected network, you can opt your network out of it by including _optout somewhere in the Wi‑Fi network name (also called the SSID). For example, mynetwork_optout or my_optout_network. When it comes to sharing, you might choose to do this if you have a Wi‑Fi network at home or at a small business where other people know the Wi‑Fi network password, but you don’t want to allow your network to be shared.
>
> To change your network name and opt out of Wi‑Fi Sense
>
> Use an Ethernet cable to connect your computer to your router or other Wi‑Fi access point.
>
> Open your web browser, and then enter the address of the configuration webpage for your Wi‑Fi router or other access point. The address is usually either http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1.
>
> If it's not one of these addresses, you can try a few other things. First, check the bottom of your router or access point, and see if there's a sticker with the address listed on it. If there isn't, you can find the address by typing ipconfig in a command prompt window if you're using Windows (or ifconfig in the command prompt on Mac OS or Linux), and then looking at the address for the Default gateway.
>
> If prompted, enter the administrator user name and password for your router or access point.
>
> If you don't know either one, check the documentation for your router or access point to find the defaults that are used.
>
> On the router configuration webpage, find a text box that's labeled Name, SSID, or something similar, and then type a new network name that has the phrase _optout in it.
>
> Save your changes if prompted, log out, and then unplug the Ethernet cable that's connecting your computer to your router.
>
> To get connected to your Wi‑Fi network again when you're done, choose the new network name, and then enter your network password when prompted.

Comment: This just reiterates the info given in the post.

Comment: @Ramhound: Good answers normally require more than easily discovered information, especially when the poster has well researched the subject. Your answers that I have seen are much better than this one and do apport a real solution. For explaining what the poster said, a link in a comment is enough. There are too many non-answers on SU that try to get the prize by sheer verbosity, and that get upvoted because they are interesting for some. SU is a Q&A site, not a blog.

Comment: @Ramhound: I can accept when an answer is an answer, but just not the best one. Explaining how to change the router's SSID to include _optout, when the poster expressly demanded some other answer, is just too much.

Comment: Just to note, i wanted to point out (because of your conversation) that the points i added from the Microsoft Q&A was added after my original post, as a way to point out that's what Microsoft officially says about the question.  It is easy to find, but i added as part of that edit. It is useful for some people, but after an argument with the OP, i gave up trying to give him more information. Even from the edits in his post, he just gives me the impression he is looking for a way to disable a feature embedded in the OS (and may not have a better answer to). HarryMC's answer is more than enough.

Comment: My solution for "Opting out" instead of changing my SSID name, since I don't use windows, I do not share, and now when people ask if they can use my network, I first ask what OS, if they say windows (or don't know -- meaning windows) I tell them NO they may not connect to my network.
If they don't have windows, I will get their MAC address to add to the whitelist (this keeps a windows user from just listening and adding with out my permission.)

Comment: White-listing isn't a bad idea, but I would not recommend flat out rejecting people based on using a windows OS.  Besides, a network isn't really secure if connecting a Windows OS makes it vulnerable. Keeping it secure is more OPSEC (Operation Security for those that don't know), so if you just allow any device to connect, the problem isn't with the device, it's with the procedures.